# Detect, from a frame, which class a method is associated with

Tags: python, super, internal, sys, python-3.7

I'm writing an incredibly hackish piece of not-quite-production code in Python, and I need some way of detecting whether a `_XYZ__foo` attribute access was called from a method defined on a class called `/_*XYZ/`. It's not quite as easy as that, though, since I need to detect the *original* method access in case anything has overridden `__getattribute__` and called `super()`.

I'm bad at explaining, so... the rules are similar to Java's `private`, except I want to prevent cheating. (Yes, I know that this is counter to the Python philosophy; bear with me here.)

My current plan of attack is:

1. Use `re.compile('_(?P<class>.*?)__(?P<name>.*)')` to detect the name of the class (with preceding `_`s stripped).
2. Climb the `super` chain with `sys._getframe(n)` to find out where the attribute access was.
3. Detect what class it was on... somehow. I'm stuck here.

I might be able to do this by emulating `super`'s walking of the MRO, but I'd much rather rely on detection because checking what's been called by `super` and what's been called by user functions is hard.

So, to my actual question. Given a frame, how can I detect which class a method is associated with? If I had access to the function object I could do `f.__qualname__[:-1-len(f.__name__)]`, but I don't (or, at least, I don't *think* I do). As is, I have no idea how to do this!

Here's a simple example that demonstrates what I want to do:

```
import sys
import re
import itertools
import builtins
from builtins import __build_class__

def build_class(func, name, *bases, metaclass=None, **kwds):
    if bases[-1] is object:
        bases = bases[:-1]
    bases += HackishClass, object
    if metaclass is None:
        return __build_class__(func, name, *bases, **kwds)
    return __build_class__(func, name, *bases, metaclass=metaclass, **kwds)

private_regex = re.compile('_(?P<class>.*?)__(?P<name>.*)')
class HackishClass:
    __slots__ = ()
    def __getattribute__(self, key):
        match = private_regex.match(key)
        if match is not None:
            for depth in itertools.count(1):
                frame = sys._getframe(depth)
                if ...:  # snip
                    # Check for the original attribute access here.
                    break
            class_name = ...  # HERE! MAGIC GOES HERE!
            if class_name != match['class']:
                raise AttributeError("This is private! Keep out.")
        return super().__getattribute__(key)

builtins.__build_class__ = build_class
```

Comment: So all you know is the method's name, and that the method is currently on the call stack?

Comment: An example of what you want to allow and prevent would probably be helpful.

Comment: @Aran-Fey And the code of the method, and a few other things. It's a shame that there isn't a [tag:hackish] or something.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I'm just trying to detect which class a method is associated with. The above is just context in case somebody spots an XY problem.

Comment: Could you show an example of what you want to do? I feel like there's an interesting problem here, but I can't figure out what it is. All this talk about `super` and MRO is confusing, and I don't understand how it's related to your problem. Some code that demonstrates what you're trying to do would be a huge help.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Example! (I forgot to ping you.)

Comment: @schwobaseggl Also example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no way to obtain the method where the attribute access occurred directly from a frame object. We can, however, obtain that method's [code object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.CodeType). We can then search the object's MRO until we find the method to which that code object belongs.

```
private_regex = re.compile('_(?P<class>.*?)__(?P<name>.*)')
class HackishClass:
    __slots__ = ()

    def __getattribute__(self, key):
        match = private_regex.match(key)
        if match is None:
            # not a private attribute, no problem
            return super().__getattribute__(key)

        # obtain the code object of the calling function
        calling_codeobj = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_code

        # iterate the MRO until we find a class with the name from `key`
        classname = match.group('class')
        for cls in type(self).mro():
            if cls.__name__ != classname:
                continue

            # check if the code object belongs to a method defined in this class
            for thing in vars(cls).values():
                if getattr(thing, '__code__', None) is calling_codeobj:
                    # found it! allow the attribute access
                    return super().__getattribute__(key)

        raise AttributeError("This is private! Keep out.")
```

A small demonstration:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__foo = 5
        print(self.__foo)

f = Foo()           # prints 5
print(f._Foo__foo)  # throws AttributeError
```

Comment: This is nowhere near as hackish as I expected the solution to be. In fact, I think this is the "one obvious way" to do it! :-D